# Skipping the temp dir or changing it at runtime with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

**See the edit at the bottom. Some info below is wrong.**

Is there a way to make FFMPEG write directly to the destination and skip the tmp dir?

If not is there a way to choose the temp dir at runtime? Say I wanted to use `/mnt/hgfs/videos/tmp` instead of the `/tmp` directory.

I know with my situation I can do a number of other things to fix the problem but I want to see if I can do either of the above first.

I have a virtual machine that uses ffmpeg to transcode files. I need to combine a bunch of large files and transcode them. The combined file can be larger than 60GB. The virtual machine's disk space is 46GB which is plenty because I have all of the videos (input and output) on a drobo mounted at `/mnt/hgfs/videos`. When I run my `ffmpeg concat` on 15 4GB files I have a 60GB file. FFMPEG first writes to the `/tmp` dir then moves it to the destination directory. Because the `/tmp` dir is on the 46GB system it gets full and FFMPEG crashes.

A few work around that may help others with similar problems: (I don't want to use these for my problem)

1) Follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697214/how-to-set-the-tmpdir-environment-variable-to-another-directory) to recompile FFMPEG with a different temp directory.

2) Follow [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5489/how-to-safely-move-tmp-to-a-different-volume) to mv `/tmp` to a larger drive and symlink it to `/tmp`.

and in my case I could have just:
3) transcoded the videos then concat them with MP4Box or FFMPEG so you never have to work with that large of a file.

**EDIT: I was wrong all along.**

FFMPEG doesn't write the file to `/tmp` then move it into the destination. I am using a node project that calls FFMPEG but it sets the destination to `/tmp` then when FFMPEG is done transcoding the video the node project moves it to the destination I want. So the whole time it wasn't FFMPEG using the `/tmp` directory.

Answer (score 1):

In the first link you gave, they are having an issue with the compilation of `ffmpeg`, not running it. Both the compiler and `ffmpeg` should use the system temp directory. So just as changing the `TMPDIR` variable allowed it to compile correctly, it should allow it to run correctly for you. The location of the temporary directory is stored in the `TMPDIR` or `TMP` environment variable.

Comment: I know this. But doesn't that compile into the ffmpeg build. Wouldn't I have the change that then recompile for that to help me?

Comment: I took a closer look at that link and edited the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: The links were just showing alternate solutions that might help other people. I know that I can change the value of TMPDIR and recompile to have FFMPEG use a different temp directory but that doesn't seem right. It seems like FFMPEG would have a built in way to specify the tmp dir at runtime. Are you saying that I can just change TMPDIR and run ffmpeg and it will use that temp dir?

Comment: That should work. Your link was about the compiler not working, as in the compiler needed to place temporary files in the temp directory. I don't think ffmpeg has a compiled-in temp directory location.

Comment: So... You are pretty much right. +1 for helping me. I was wrong all along though. FFMPEG isn't even what is putting it in the `/tmp` dir. FFMPEG isn't even using the tmp dir. I am using a node project that calls FFMPEG. That program uses `/tmp` as the destination for FFMPEG then copies it to the actual destination.